# ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom 404 Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to setup a custom 404 error page. In my web.config I have this in my system.web

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/Error404" />
    </customErrors>
```

I have this method in my HomeController

```
public ActionResult Error404()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and this my view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error404";
}

<h2>Error404</h2>
```

My problem is when I goto the URL that does not exist in my website, I do not get my custom page. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Do you mean when you run the site locally and go to http://locahost/badurl, you don't see the custom 404 page?  Or do you mean on your web host/real site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The custom error pages are not enabled for local in your code. So, if you are testing this locally it will not work. Change the web.config entry as below to enable custom error pages locally as well

```
<customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/Error404" />
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: Thank you very much